# Uniformly converging

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Can someone help me how to conclude if the following converges uniformly:

$\frac{1}{nx}$$Χ_{(1/n,1]}$$(x)$

where $Χ$ is the characteristic function?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you encounter this problem? Where did you get stuck? Provide us more information so we can help you with the parts you need help on, instead of letting us throw the complete answer on your lap

Comment: I assume you mean (uniform) convergence on $\mathbb{R}$ to $0$?

Comment: For any $n$, the function value can be made arbitrarily close to $1$ by choosing $x$ slightly larger than $1/n$. But the sequence converges pointwise to zero. What can you conclude?

Comment: The sequence converges uniformly on every compact subset of $(0, \, \infty)$. Though you cannot show this until you fix a compact subset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not hard to see that $f_n\to 0$ pointwise everywhere. If $f_n$ converged uniformly to $0$ on $\mathbb R,$ we would have

$$\tag 1 \sup_{\mathbb R}|f_n|\to 0.$$

But for each $n>1,$ $f_n(2/n) = 1/2.$ Thus the supremums in $(1)$ are all at least $1/2$ for $n>1,$ showing $(1)$ fails. Thus $f_n$ fails to converge uniformly to $0$

Comment: I am close-minded. Or rather something about two sides of the same coin, if you prefer idioms.

Comment: Minor nit: $f_n(1/n) = 0$ since the characteristic function in the definition of $f_n$ is on the open-ended interval $(1/n, 1]$. But the supremums are all $1$, so the rest of the argument is fine.

Comment: I carelessly took it to be $\chi_{[1/n,1]}.$ I'll edit, thanks.